# How to maintain the accordion menu( in masterpage) after postback

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery. Can you please provide the complete code for Maintaining the accordion menu( in masterpage) after postback. How to use below code in my application?

I have a master page and some content pages. When the link in the master page is clicked the total menu is collapsing. But i need to open the last menu clicked.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidAccordionIndex" runat="server" Value="0" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var activeIndex = parseInt($('#<%=hidAccordionIndex.ClientID %>').val());

        $("#accordion").accordion({
            autoHeight:false,
            event:"mousedown",
            active:activeIndex,
            change:function(event, ui)
            {
                var index = $(this).children('h3').index(ui.newHeader);
                $('#<%=hidAccordionIndex.ClientID %>').val(index);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have to save the current state on the *accordion* before postback and rebuild / restate it on *.ready()* event.

Comment: Hi Dear,Thanks for ur reply. I have done it by following the below link     http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu-plugin/getting-started/. But now facing a different issue. The cookie is not cleared on browser tab close. How can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try The [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mayanksaxena19/98a5yfh2/),

```
$(function() {

    $("#accordion").accordion({ // initialising the accordian
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            var index = $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active"); // Getting the current Opened/Active Tab index value (Starting from Zero 0)
            $('#hidAccordionIndex').val(index); // Setting Active tab value to Hidden Field
        }
    });

    $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", parseInt($('#hidAccordionIndex').val(), 10)); // Setting Active Tab value to Accordian 

});
```

Hope it helps...